# Excel VBA code to bulk convert rtf files in a folder to pdf files

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am a novice to VBA coding, but would like to know how to create a macro in excel that allows me to choose a folder in which there are rtf files, and convert them all to pdf within the same folder.

Any help is appreciated.

Kind regards

Comment: Although your question is fairly well worded, it doesn't show any research effort. I have helped you in this instance, but stack should not be your starting point for a problem, google should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use Word to open the `.rtf` and convert it to PDF. Excel is designed to display spreadsheets not documents, but you can automate this from Excel by referencing the Word object library.

Use the built-in FileDialog to prompt you for folder selection, and as an entry point to the macro.

```
'Add a Reference Microsoft Word Object Library

Sub ConvertRtfToPDF()

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show() Then
            ConvertFiles GetFiles(.SelectedItems(1), ".rtf")
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

This is the function that does the conversion, it takes an array of files and converts them all to PDF:

```
Sub ConvertFiles(files() As String)

    Dim wd As New Word.Application
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim file As Variant

    For Each file In files
        Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(file, ReadOnly:=True)
        doc.ExportAsFixedFormat Replace(file, ".rtf", ".pdf"), 17
        doc.Close
    Next file

    wd.Quit

End Sub
```

This function returns an array of filenames, given a folder name:

```
Function GetFiles(folder As String, extension As String) As String()

    Dim files() As String
    ReDim files(0)

    file = Dir(folder & "\")
    While (file <> "")
        If Right(file, Len(extension)) = extension Then
            files(UBound(files)) = folder & "\" & file
            ReDim Preserve files(UBound(files) + 1)
        End If
        file = Dir
    Wend
    ReDim Preserve files(UBound(files) - 1)
    GetFiles = files

End Function
```

Paste all that into a module and run the ConvertRtfToPDF function, you will be prompted to select a folder and it will convert every `.rtf` in that folder to a `.pdf`.